# Selenium: How to make RemoteDriver always attached to the current browser tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing a windows app that can manipulate browsers with voice commands.
I want to properly handle cases when users adding some tabs and changing selected tab how they want.
Turns out RemoteDriver works only with one tab and can switch focus to another tabs by providing tab handle.
But i don't know how to get selected tab handle and always check for selected tab changed or is there exists a way to always work with selected tab?

Comment: my app now working only with the first tab. sadly.
i will try soon to somehow write a code ti switch current selenium tab if needed on any action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is a browser automation tool used to test websites. It is not intended to be used together with outside interaction (user interaction, voice control test or whatever) and therefore does not have any functionality for what you want. From selenium's point of view, it should always know exactly what window (tab, browser window, or frame) is currently active, because an automation test should be performed in a controlled environment. As in, Selenium and your selenium test control the environment in which selenium is being used, and nothing else.

Comment: You are right, but there is no other easy way to manipulate chromium browsers.

Comment: Selenium Driver can be integrated with other automation tools.  Such as `AppliTools`. You need to run `Selenium Hub` and point it to `AppliTools` instance.

Comment: OP is writing his own app in his free time. I sincerely doubt he's willing to spend €200 a month on an AppliTools license...